# Pointer passed to function changes unexpectedly

Tags: c++, pointers, pthreads, ld-preload

I'm designing a preloader-based lock tracing utility that attaches to Pthreads, and I've run into a weird issue. The program works by providing wrappers that replace relevant Pthreads functions at runtime; these do some logging, and then pass the args to the real Pthreads function to do the work. They do not modify the arguments passed to them, obviously. However, when testing, I discovered that the condition variable pointer passed to my pthread_cond_wait() wrapper does not match the one that gets passed to the underlying Pthreads function, which promptly crashes with "futex facility returned an unexpected error code," which, from what I've gathered, usually indicates an invalid sync object passed in. Relevant stack trace from GDB:

```
#8  __pthread_cond_wait (cond=0x7f1b14000d12, mutex=0x55a2b961eec0) at pthread_cond_wait.c:638
#9  0x00007f1b1a47b6ae in pthread_cond_wait (cond=0x55a2b961f290, lk=0x55a2b961eec0)
    at pthread_trace.cpp:56
```

I'm pretty mystified. Here's the code for my pthread_cond_wait() wrapper:

```
int pthread_cond_wait(pthread_cond_t* cond, pthread_mutex_t* lk) {
        // log arrival at wait
        the_tracer.add_event(lktrace::event::COND_WAIT, (size_t) cond);
        // run pthreads function
        GET_REAL_FN(pthread_cond_wait, int, pthread_cond_t*, pthread_mutex_t*);
        int e = REAL_FN(cond, lk);
        if (e == 0) the_tracer.add_event(lktrace::event::COND_LEAVE, (size_t) cond);
        else {
                the_tracer.add_event(lktrace::event::COND_ERR, (size_t) cond);
        }
        return e;
}

// GET_REAL_FN is defined as:
#define GET_REAL_FN(name, rtn, params...) \
        typedef rtn (*real_fn_t)(params); \
        static const real_fn_t REAL_FN = (real_fn_t) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, #name); \
        assert(REAL_FN != NULL) // semicolon absence intentional
```

And here's the code for __pthread_cond_wait in glibc 2.31 (this is the function that gets called if you call pthread_cond_wait normally, it has a different name because of versioning stuff. The stack trace above confirms that this is the function that REAL_FN points to):

```
int
__pthread_cond_wait (pthread_cond_t *cond, pthread_mutex_t *mutex)
{
  /* clockid is unused when abstime is NULL. */
  return __pthread_cond_wait_common (cond, mutex, 0, NULL);
}
```

As you can see, neither of these functions modifies cond, yet it is not the same in the two frames. Examining the two different pointers in a core dump shows that they point to different contents, as well. I can also see in the core dump that cond does not appear to change in my wrapper function (i.e. it's still equal to 0x5... in frame 9 at the crash point, which is the call to REAL_FN). I can't really tell which pointer is correct by looking at their contents, but I'd assume it's the one passed in to my wrapper from the target application. Both pointers point to valid segments for program data (marked ALLOC, LOAD, HAS_CONTENTS).

My tool is definitely causing the error somehow, the target application runs fine if it is not attached. What am I missing?

UPDATE: Actually, this doesn't appear to be what's causing the error, because calls to my pthread_cond_wait() wrapper succeed many times before the error occurs, and exhibit similar behavior (pointer value changing between frames without explanation) each time. I'm leaving the question open, though, because I still don't understand what's going on here and I'd like to learn.

UPDATE 2: As requested, here's the code for tracer.add_event():

```
// add an event to the calling thread's history
// hist_entry ctor gets timestamp & stack trace
void tracer::add_event(event e, size_t obj_addr) {
        size_t tid = get_tid();
        hist_map::iterator hist = histories.contains(tid);
        assert(hist != histories.end());
        hist_entry ev (e, obj_addr);
        hist->second.push_back(ev);
}

// hist_entry ctor:
hist_entry::hist_entry(event e, size_t obj_addr) :
        ts(chrono::steady_clock::now()), ev(e), addr(obj_addr) {

        // these are set in the tracer ctor     
        assert(start_addr && end_addr);

        void* buf[TRACE_DEPTH];
        int v = backtrace(buf, TRACE_DEPTH);
        int a = 0;
        // find first frame outside of our own code
        while (a < v && start_addr < (size_t) buf[a] &&
                end_addr > (size_t) buf[a]) ++a;
        // skip requested amount of frames
        a += TRACE_SKIP;
        if (a >= v) a = v-1;
        caller = buf[a];
}
```

histories is a lock-free concurrent hashmap from libcds (mapping tid->per-thread vectors of hist_entry), and its iterators are guaranteed to be thread-safe as well. GNU docs say backtrace() is thread-safe, and there's no data races mentioned in the CPP docs for steady_clock::now(). get_tid() just calls pthread_self() using the same method as the wrapper functions, and casts its result to size_t.

Comment: seems like it's time for assembly code debugging?

Comment: What does `the_tracer.add_event` do? Specifically wondering how it takes the second parameter (by value or by reference).

Comment: The parameter is passed by value (and not treated as a pointer, as you can see from the cast)

Comment: Which compiler are you using? You don't seem to be using variable macro arguments properly, which I think results in you only passing one parameter to `REAL_FN`.

Comment: I'm using gcc 9.3. That macro definition is well-formed; you're allowed to name your varargs if you want : https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

Comment: I don't particularly see the value here of employing the GCC *extension* that allows you to specify an alternative name for `__VA_ARGS__`, but I'm confident that that's not the problem.  If it were, then the compiler would complain about function arguments being mismatched with the function prototype.

Comment: Is `the_tracer.add_event()` thread-safe?

Comment: More generally, since I don't see anything wrong with the code presented, but `the_tracer.add_event()` is *not* presented, I'm inclined to suspect an issue in that method.  If it gets inlined then it's entirely plausible that a buffer overrun or similar UB there could manifest as an unexpected modification to the caller's local variables. (And maybe even if it's *not* inlined.  UB manifests in mysterious ways.)

Comment: @JohnBollinger Added code for tracer.add_event() and a constructor it calls. It definitely shouldn't be getting inlined, it's linked in from a separate object file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah, figured it out! The issue is that Glibc exposes multiple versions of  pthread_cond_wait(), for backwards compatibility. The version I reproduce in my question is the current version, the one we want to call. The version that dlsym() was finding is the backwards-compatible version:

```
int
__pthread_cond_wait_2_0 (pthread_cond_2_0_t *cond, pthread_mutex_t *mutex)
{
  if (cond->cond == NULL)
    {
      pthread_cond_t *newcond;

      newcond = (pthread_cond_t *) calloc (sizeof (pthread_cond_t), 1);
      if (newcond == NULL)
        return ENOMEM;

      if (atomic_compare_and_exchange_bool_acq (&cond->cond, newcond, NULL))
        /* Somebody else just initialized the condvar.  */
        free (newcond);
    }

  return __pthread_cond_wait (cond->cond, mutex);
}
```

As you can see, this version tail-calls the current one, which is probably why this took so long to detect: GDB is normally pretty good at detecting frames elided by tail calls, but I'm guessing it didn't detect this one because the functions have the "same" name (and the error doesn't affect the mutex functions because they don't expose multiple versions). [This blog post](https://blog.fesnel.com/blog/2009/08/25/preloading-with-multiple-symbol-versions/) goes into much more detail, coincidentally specifically about pthread_cond_wait(). I stepped through this function many times while debugging and sort of tuned it out, because every call into glibc is wrapped in multiple layers of indirection; I only realized what was going on when I set a breakpoint on the pthread_cond_wait symbol, instead of a line number, and it stopped at this function.

Anyway, this explains the changing pointer phenomenon: what happens is that the old, incorrect function gets called, reinterprets the pthread_cond_t object as a struct containing a pointer to a pthread_cond_t object, allocates a new pthread_cond_t for that pointer, and then passes the newly allocated one to the new, correct function. The frame of the old function gets elided by the tail-call, and to a GDB backtrace after leaving the old function it looks like the correct function gets called directly from my wrapper, with a mysteriously changed argument.

The fix for this was simple: GNU provides the libdl extension dlvsym(), which is like dlsym() but also takes a version string. Looking for pthread_cond_wait with version string "GLIBC_2.3.2" solves the problem. Note that these versions do not usually correspond to the current version (i.e. pthread_create()/exit() have version string "GLIBC_2.2.5"), so they need to be looked up on a per-function basis. The correct string can be determined either by looking at the compat_symbol() or versioned_symbol() macros that are somewhere near the function definition in the glibc source, or by using readelf to see the names of the symbols in the compiled library (mine has "pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2" and "pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.2.5").