# "Futex facility returned an unexpected error code" in preloader-based lock profiler

Tags: c++, pthreads, glibc, condition-variable, ld-preload

I'm designing a preloader-based thread profiling utility that attaches to Pthreads, and it seems to be causing an error for profiled programs that use condition variables. Yesterday, I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901828/pointer-passed-to-function-changes-unexpectedly)  about some strange behavior that I thought was causing the error, but further investigation revealed that not to be the cause (still interested in an answer there as well, though).

So, my program works by providing wrappers that replace relevant Pthreads functions at runtime; these do some logging, and then pass the args to the real Pthreads function to do the work. They don't modify the arguments passed to Pthreads. When my tool is attached to a test program (the Kyotocabinet test suite, specifically), the program crashes inside one of pthread_cond_wait/signal/broadcast (test program is nondeterministic) with "the futex facility returned an unexpected error". The code for these functions:

```
int pthread_cond_wait(pthread_cond_t* cond, pthread_mutex_t* lk) {
        // log arrival at wait
        the_tracer.add_event(lktrace::event::COND_WAIT, (size_t) cond);
        // run pthreads function
        GET_REAL_FN(pthread_cond_wait, int, pthread_cond_t*, pthread_mutex_t*);
        int e = REAL_FN(cond, lk);
        if (e == 0) the_tracer.add_event(lktrace::event::COND_LEAVE, (size_t) cond);
        else {
                the_tracer.add_event(lktrace::event::COND_ERR, (size_t) cond);
        }
        return e;
}

int pthread_cond_signal(pthread_cond_t* cond) {
        // log cond signal
        the_tracer.add_event(lktrace::event::COND_SIGNAL, (size_t) cond);
        // run pthreads function
        GET_REAL_FN(pthread_cond_signal, int, pthread_cond_t*);
        return REAL_FN(cond);
}

int pthread_cond_broadcast(pthread_cond_t* cond) {
        the_tracer.add_event(lktrace::event::COND_BRDCST, (size_t) cond);
        GET_REAL_FN(pthread_cond_broadcast, int, pthread_cond_t*);
        return REAL_FN(cond);
}

// GET_REAL_FN is defined as:
#define GET_REAL_FN(name, rtn, params...) \
        typedef rtn (*real_fn_t)(params); \
        static const real_fn_t REAL_FN = (real_fn_t) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, #name); \
        assert(REAL_FN != NULL) // semicolon absence intentional
```

I can see with GDB that calls to these functions succeed many times before failing with an error. I should also note that my tool has similar wrappers for pthread_mutex_lock/unlock() that have yet to produce any error like this (and have been tested much more than the condvar ones).

It gets weirder, though. The error comes from the futex_wake function (glibc 2.31, removed some comments to save space):

```
static __always_inline void
futex_wake (unsigned int* futex_word, int processes_to_wake, int private)
{
  int res = lll_futex_wake (futex_word, processes_to_wake, private);
  if (res >= 0)
    return;
  switch (res)
    {   
    case -EFAULT:
    case -EINVAL:
      return;
    case -ENOSYS: /* Must have been caused by a glibc bug.  */
    /* No other errors are documented at this time.  */
    default:
      futex_fatal_error (); 
    }   
}
```

lll_futex_wake() calls the futex wake syscall, and futex_fatal_error() is what prints the error message and crashes out. As you can see, the only error that's considered fatal (assuming the syscall isn't returning undocumented errors) is ENOSYS [see update below; according to strace, it's returning EINVAL]. However, that makes no sense. The comment says that that can only be caused by a glibc bug, and the [glibc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html) says this:

> “Function not implemented.” This indicates that the function called is not implemented at all, either in the C library itself or in the operating system. When you get this error, you can be sure that this particular function will always fail with ENOSYS unless you install a new version of the C library or the operating system.

But, as noted above, calls to these functions succeed many times before the error (and, in general, I'm *pretty sure* that futexes are implemented on bog-standard Ubuntu 20.04). And it's almost certainly not a bug in glibc, since it only happens when my tool is attached. Some other answers I've seen say that "futex facility returned an unexpected error code" indicates an invalid sync object, but I don't think that's what's going on here because a) my wrapper functions don't modify the arguments passed to them and b) those posts were about semaphores, not condvars; my understanding is that the pthread_cond_* functions return EINVAL if the condvar is invalid, they don't crash the entire program.

So, in general, I'm pretty mystified by this error. Is my tool corrupting the stack somehow? Is it an ABI issue (target program & my tool are written in C++)? Is the syscall returning an undocumented error? I've tested the tool on a different, much simpler target program that uses condvars, and the error does not occur there. If anyone knows another more complex open-source program that uses Pthreads condvars (or C++ std::condition_variable) that I could try to reproduce it on, that would be helpful in finding a solution.

Update: Did an strace, as suggested. Strace reports that the syscall returns EINVAL (process 97114 is the error source):

```
[pid 97114] futex(0x7fc3f0000d3a, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 97108] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid 97114] <... futex resumed>)        = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
[pid 97108] futex(0x7fc3f0000d3e, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 97114] writev(2, [{iov_base="The futex facility returned an u"..., iov_len=54}], 1 <unfinished ...>
The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.
```

However, I have no idea why an EINVAL would cause a fatal error. It doesn't appear to do so in the source. And even if so, I have no idea why my tracer would cause that, given that it doesn't modify the arguments passed to Pthreads.

UPDATE: here's the relevant part of a backtrace in the core dump, from GDB:

```
#3  0x00007f0eb8296460 in __GI___libc_fatal (
    message=message@entry=0x7f0eb809e000 "The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:164
#4  0x00007f0eb80963fa in futex_fatal_error () at ../sysdeps/nptl/futex-internal.h:380
#5  futex_wake (private=<optimized out>, processes_to_wake=<optimized out>, 
    futex_word=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/nptl/futex-internal.h:380
#6  __condvar_confirm_wakeup (private=<optimized out>, cond=<optimized out>)
    at pthread_cond_wait.c:55
#7  __pthread_cond_wait_common (abstime=0x0, clockid=0, mutex=0x5566318e7ec0, 
    cond=0x7f0ea8000d12) at pthread_cond_wait.c:425
#8  __pthread_cond_wait (cond=0x7f0ea8000d12, mutex=0x5566318e7ec0) at pthread_cond_wait.c:638
#9  0x00007f0eb88a3620 in pthread_cond_wait (cond=0x5566318e8290, lk=0x5566318e7ec0)
    at pthread_trace.cpp:56
#10 0x00007f0eb87b6106 in kyotocabinet::CondVar::wait (this=<optimized out>, 
    mutex=<optimized out>) at kcthread.cc:1839
```

Comment: If you use `strace` you will be able to see the futex call and  the error it returned.

Comment: I would be inclined to guess that the `EINVAL` produces a fatal error somewhere farther up the call chain.  Most likely in the real `pthread_cond_wait()`.  Remember that `strace` traces *system calls*.  Ordinary user-space function calls are invisible to it, and in this case, the call to `futex_wake()` can be expected to have been inlined, anyway.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't think that's the case, nothing up the caller chain calls futex_fatal_error(), which is definitely the function that's raising the signal (everything above futex_wake() is in Pthreads, so it would be weird for it to use a futex function to report errors anyway). I will attach the relevant frames of a GDB backtrace above for reference.